# Select [com funções agregadas] group by em Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Como converto o seguinte select

```
SELECT     TOP (60) COUNT(*) AS QTD, SUM(Duration) AS Total, AVG(Duration) AS Media, MIN(Duration) AS Menor, LEFT(TextData, 80) AS TextData
FROM         Traces WITH (nolock)
WHERE     (StartTime >= DATEADD(D, - 7, GETDATE())) AND (DataBaseName IN ('database_1', 'database_2'))
GROUP BY TextData, DataBaseName
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

estou tentando da seguinte maneira:

```
var lambda = ctx.Traces.Where(q => q.DataBaseName == "database_1" || q.DataBaseName == "database_2")
         .GroupBy(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })
         .Select(b => new { 
                 QTD = b.Count(), 
                 Total = b.Sum(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 Media = b.Average(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 Menor = b.Min(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 textData = b.Select(b2 => b2.TextData) //aqui o problema
                          })
          .OrderByDescending(b => b.Total)
          .Take(10)
          .ToList();
```

porém não consigo recuperar o TextData

ele retorna algo do tipo:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

os outros campos estão ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque assim:

```
var lambda = ctx.Traces
         .Where(q => q.DataBaseName == "database_1" || q.DataBaseName == "database_2")
         .GroupBy(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })
         .Select(b => new { 
                 QTD = b.Count(), 
                 Total = b.Sum(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 Media = b.Average(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 Menor = b.Min(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 textData = EntityFunctions.Left(b.Key.TextData, 80)})
          .OrderByDescending(b => b.Total)
          .Take(10)
          .ToList();
```

ou

```
var lambda = ctx.Traces
         .Where(q => q.DataBaseName == "database_1" || q.DataBaseName == "database_2")
         .GroupBy(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })
         .Select(b => new { 
                 QTD = b.Count(), 
                 Total = b.Sum(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 Media = b.Average(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 Menor = b.Min(b1 => b1.Duration),
                 textData = b.Key.TextData.Substring(0,80)})
          .OrderByDescending(b => b.Total)
          .Take(10)
          .ToList();
```

`Key` = `(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })`, ou seja, é o agrupamento que você montou podendo ser `b.Key.TextData` e `b.Key.DataBaseName`

Comment: perfeito, o que é a função key? e como limito 80 caracteres para o retorno?na própria lambda expression

Comment: b.Key.TextData.Substring(0,80) ?

Comment: DbFunctions.Left(b.Key.TextData, 80), tem que usar o DbFunctions...

Comment: xii é entity framework 5..Dbfunctions é do 6 ?

Comment: mude para EntityFunctions.Left